# MinimalAp IEndpointFilter MapGet Get Pattern

Tags: c#, routes, minimal-apis

In the IEndpointFilter would like to get the route used.

```
app.MapGet("/get/{productId:guid}", ......


public class MyFilter : IEndpointFilter
{
    public async ValueTask<object?> InvokeAsync(EndpointFilterInvocationContext context, EndpointFilterDelegate next)
    {

    //Getting it here /get/{productId:guid}
    return await next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HttpContext.GetEndpoint()` method and then check if endpoint is `RouteEndpoint`:

```cs
class MyFilter : IEndpointFilter
{
    public async ValueTask<object?> InvokeAsync(EndpointFilterInvocationContext context, EndpointFilterDelegate next)
    {
        var endpoint = context.HttpContext.GetEndpoint();
        if (endpoint is RouteEndpoint re1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(re1.RoutePattern.RawText);
        }

        return await next(context);
    }
}
```

Or do manually what `GetEndpoint` does itself:

```cs
var endpointFeature = context.HttpContext.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>();
if (endpointFeature?.Endpoint is RouteEndpoint re)
{
    Console.WriteLine(re.RoutePattern.RawText);
}
```